# Flex 4 Dates, Bug or what? im so confused

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I'm not sure whether it's a bug or what. But it's making my life worse.

I'm doing a Flex 4 application that has a calendar component in an invisible 'state' when I pass comp2.selectedDate(2006,2); 
and debug at line 3, date has only 2006 year and 0 month.

Why so? Why isn't it getting month = 2 as well?

Thanks in advance

```
public function selectedDate(year:Number, month:Number, day:* = null):void{
var date:Date = new Date(year, month, day);
dateChooser.selectedDate = date;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, everything looks in order here.  The only possible issue I see is passing in null for the day when creating a new Date.  The default is 1, you may want to try setting the day to 1 when you detect null being passed into your method for the day.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Good catch. Perhaps a better option would be changing the signature of the method to accept a Number for the day and make it default to 1. `public function selectedDate(year:Number, month:Number, day:Number = 1):void`